# How to know which store consumed shopify webhook?

Tags: shopify, webhooks, shopify-app

I have created a Shopify app which will allow different store owners to download it and to configure different Web-hooks of their choice like "Order Create", "Order Update" etc...

Each and every Web-hooks are getting configured properly and working fine.

But my issue is "how to know that call to web-hook method is made due to action performed by which of the store"

In sort I wanted to know action performed on which store has triggered web-hook method to be executed.

Comment: Not sure I understood your question correctly, but you have to have unique webhook urls per store, on your and. And use the web hook url param to identify which store is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's part of the headers and handshake sent by Shopify to your app.

Regardless of the type of webhook you get a header X-Shopify-Shop-Domain that contains the permanent-shop.myshopify.com address of the shop. [see](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/events/webhook)

Answer (score 0):

Shopify package has a method that allow you to register a handler for each topic

```js
import Shopify from "@shopify/shopify-api";

  Shopify.Webhooks.Registry.addHandler(topic, {
    path: "/webhooks",
    webhookHandler: handler,
  });
```

The handler arguments have the shop that is called for that webhook

Here's an example for product delete handler

```js
export async function deleteProductHandler(topic: string, shop: string, body: any) {
...
}
```